# Heat Equation with X> 0

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to solve the following:
$$
u_t = ku_{xx} \quad x>0 \quad t>0
\\
u(x, 0) = 0  \quad x>0
\\
u_x(0, t) = g(t)
$$
plus, $u$ and $u_x$ approach 0 when $ x $ approaches $ \infty$

I want to derive the solution is given by:

$$ \Large u(x, t) = -\sqrt{\frac{k}{\pi}} \int_0^t \frac{g(\tau)}{\sqrt{t - \tau}} e^{- \frac{x^2}{4k(t-\tau)}}$$

I went about it with fourier transforming both sides of the PDE:

$$ \frac{d(\hat u(\omega)) }{dt} = -\omega^2k \ \hat u (\omega)$$

$$\implies \hat u(\omega) = Ae^{-\omega^2\ k \ t} $$
but from the initial conditions:
$$ A = \hat u (\omega, 0)  = 0$$

and from here I don't know how to proceed, Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Using the Laplace transform we have

$$
sU(x,s)-kU_{xx}(x,s) = 0, \ \ U_x(0,s) = G(s),\ \ \lim_{x\to \infty}U(x,s)=0
$$

Solving for $x$ we have

$$
U(x,s) = \psi_1(s)e^{\sqrt{\frac sk}x}+\psi_2(s)e^{-\sqrt{\frac sk}x}
$$

but as $\lim_{x\to \infty}U(x,s)=0$ we follow with

$$
U(x,s) = \psi_2(s)e^{-\sqrt{\frac sk}x}, \ \ U_x(0,s) = G(s)
$$

so

$$
\phi_2(s) = -\sqrt{\frac ks}G(s)
$$

and

$$
U(x,s) = -\sqrt{\frac ks}G(s)e^{-\sqrt{\frac sk}x}
$$

and finally we can use the convolution theorem

$$
u(x,t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac ks}e^{-\sqrt{\frac sk}x}\right)\circledast g(t)
$$

NOTE

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac ks}e^{-\sqrt{\frac sk}x}\right) = -\sqrt{\frac {k}{\pi}}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4k t}}}{\sqrt{t}}
$$